# Jfilechooser & output arraylist

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

- I have an arraylist of Strings I'd like to write to a text file
- I'd like it so that when the user clicks save, a browser will open and the user can choose the name of the textfile to save and the location.
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html has been my resource, I feel like I'm missing something in my code. 

  [image]
- Sorry that it is a pic instead of code snippet [formatting problems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code doesn't wait for the user-input. Correct usage of a `JFileChooser` would be (as shown in the docs):

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
//set some properties if necassary

if(jfc.showSaveDialog() == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    //do some stuff
}
```